# Failed to resolve: java-ipfs-http-client:1.3.3

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement IPFS for Java and I came across an error of "`Failed to resolve: com.github.ipfs:1.3.3`'

build.gradle file

**Here i added implementation 'java-ipfs-http-client:1.3.3**

```
 plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 32
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.kornerz.web3kornerzapptest"
            minSdk 24
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'java-ipfs-http-client:1.3.3'
    
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }

settings.gradle file
```

****here I added ' maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }****

```
pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            gradlePluginPortal()
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    rootProject.name = "testApplication"
    include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong dependency format. Change this:

`implementation 'java-ipfs-http-client:1.3.3'`

to this:

`implementation 'com.github.ipfs:java-ipfs-http-client:1.3.3'`

Comment: I solved it before, but the solution was exactly this, so I mark your answer as solved